# How can I pass body of a request to bugsnag?

Tags: bugsnag

Recently I am trying to use Bugsnag in a go-project. I am able to send Bugsnag notification from my project using the package: https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-go. But, whenever I open up the error in Bugsnag, I can only see request URL and a header. I want to see to the body of the request as well. Otherwise, it's not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the body of the request as [`MetaData`](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/go/net-http/#sending-diagnostic-data).

```golang
md := bugsnag.MetaData{}
md.AddStruct("requestBody", reqBodyAsStruct)
bugsnag.Notify(err, md)
```

You probably want to create a middleware function and give this to [`bugsnag.OnBeforeNotify`](https://godoc.org/github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-go#OnBeforeNotify) instead of having to use `bugsnag.MetaData` everywhere. In this case, you can pass in the `*http.Request` directly. You may wish to use [this function as a starting point](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-go/blob/master/middleware.go#L63) for writing this middleware function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, using metadata would be the correct approach but I would suggest using [environment variables](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/go/net-http/configuration-options/#adding-metadata) to make custom metadata available to both handles errors and unhandled panics.

```
BUGSNAG_METADATA_request_body=requestBody
```

This would add the following metadata to the `request` tab in the event of an error:

```
body: {
         "object": {
           "a": "b",
           "c": "d",
         },
         "string": "Hello World"
      }
```